# Showing fields with auto_now=True through a forms.ModelForm

Tags: python, django

I have a ModelForm with the following field definition:

```
updated_at = models.DateTimeField("Last-Modified", auto_now=True)
```

And when I do this in my form:

```
class Meta:
    model = Page
    fields = ('title', 'views', 'updated_at')
```

I get: `Unknown field(s) (updated_at) specified for Page` exception.

If I remove `auto_now=True` it works but I don't want to do that. I just want to display `updated_at` in my template, it will not be manually editable.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10033422/cant-display-datefield-on-form-with-auto-now-true and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1737017/django-auto-now-and-auto-now-add.

Comment: possible duplicate of [DateTimeField doesn't show in admin system](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6386172/datetimefield-doesnt-show-in-admin-system), http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1737017/django-auto-now-and-auto-now-add, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10033422/cant-display-datefield-on-form-with-auto-now-true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `editable` param to the define field:

```
updated_ad = models.DateTimeField('Last Modefied', auto_now=True, editable=True)
```